# Do transactions in Ripple have a TXID of sorts, or not?

Tags: transactions, protocol, ripple

Do transactions in [Ripple](https://ripple.com/) have a transaction ID of sorts just like Bitcoin transactions, or are they identified in some other way?

Answer (score 5):

Ripple transactions have a 256-bit transaction ID that is a hash of the inner transaction and the signature.

Comment: How can these be accessed? In the ripple.com web client there is no mention of them...

Comment: In the client's balance and history pages entries can be clicked for details of the transaction. The detail page includes the transaction hash. The resultant URL includes the transaction hash and you can swap in any other transaction hash you want to see it's details.